# Where is Frank Zappa's "Lumpy Gravy" in the movie

Tags: lyrics, soundtrack, frank-zappa

Where in the film "More American Graffiti" is Frank Zappa's *Lumpy Gravy*? It's listed on the [soundtrack](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079576/soundtrack), but I can't hear it anywhere.

> Lumpy Gravy
>   Written and performed by Frank Zappa
>   Courtesy of Bizarre Records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard find because it is not an actual melody from the album, but just a short sequence of spoken words.

In this link, you will find the [intro sequence](https://youtu.be/dhFuJtWhbeM?t=31) of the movie *More American Graffiti*. At 0:31 you will hear a short snippet of dialogue.

Here, on the Frank Zappa's album *Lumpy Gravy*, you will find the song [*Very Distraughtening*](https://youtu.be/uwyH9rAkugI?t=929) which has the same dialogue at its intro.

> Ah, that one again. It's a little pig with wings.